# CScript:Timestamp since epoch in milliseconds?

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, epoch, wsh

I need to get the current time-stamp in milli-seconds since the Unix epoch.

I got

```
WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())
```

from answer to this question:

[Is there a way to get epoch time using a Windows command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454112/is-there-a-way-to-get-epoch-time-using-a-dos-command-if-not-can-the-date-time)

but it doesn't support  `"ms"` for the first parameter.

Is there a way to get the above mentioned timestamp in millisecond, using CScript or any other method runnable from `.bat` or as a CScript?

Comment: try this `c:\> powershell Get-Date -UFormat %s`

Comment: @npocmaka can you write the code multiplies that number with 1000 round and put it as an answer, I will be happy to give accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\>for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=.," %a in ('powershell Get-Date -UFormat %s') do echo %a%b
```

if you intend to use this in batch script you'll need double %

or

```
C:\>powershell [float](Get-Date -UFormat %s)*1000
```

Comment: Your `for /f loop` doesn't work, you need a "space" between `in` and `(`.